# Register people on website with data from Excel

Tags: macos, forms, excel, web, automator

I teach in the classroom and also online. I would like to register my students (from whom I have the name, address, birthdate and email address in an Excel sheet) on our website. They are supposed to do so themselves but not everybody is doing that. It is part of the course though to take the online lessons. Is there a way to automatically fill out the form on the website using the Excel data I have? I have a MAC, so I was thinking about MAC automator but I am not so familiar with this kind of stuff. Thanks.

Added 06-08-2012: I cannot post the link since it's not a public website. The form is similar to the customer registration form from xtCommerce shops.

Comment: A link to the sign up form will help

Comment: Is there a scripting language you feel sufficiently comfortable with (AppleScript, Ruby, Python, Perl, JavaScript)? Straight Automator is not going to cut it.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this with Perl, using the Perl modules [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.59/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm) and [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm).

Use the former to extract data from the spreadsheet, and the latter to navigate to the website  , fill in the fields, and submit the form.